# Win 32 API: SHFileOperation merge folders

Tags: windows, api, shfileoperation

I have 2 folders:

```
m:\folder1
```

and

```
m:\folder2
```

I would like to merge folder2 with folder1 so that only folder1 exists.

I tried using SHFileOperation

```
With SHFileOp
    .wFunc = FO_FUNC
    .pFrom = "m:\folder2"
    .pTo = "m:\folder1"
    .fFlags = FO_MOVE
End With
```

...but that put m:\folder2 into m:\folder1\folder2.
But that was not what I wanted.

Is SHFileOperation the valid approach to do that and if yes, how should that be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try `.pFrom = "m:\folder2\*.*`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move all the files in the folder, you need:

```
.pFrom = "m:\folder2\*.*"
```